# Can Spring Boot merge local profile with a bundled profile of the same name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot can bundle external application configuration and profile overrides in `src/main/resources/`. Additional profiles can be loaded from the file system at runtime.

Given bundled configuration files

```
src/main/resources
├── application.yml
└── application-prod.yml
```

and local configuration

```
config
└── application-prod.yml
```

can Spring *reliably* merge the `prod` profile? If so, what are the conflict resolution rules?

The documentation details profiles in general and bundled versus local configuration but does not seem to address the case where a selected profile has both bundled and local configuration.

[Relevant Spring Boot 2.1.3 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

Comment: THe order is specified in the same section at the top -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config. That is the order in which files are processed. So anything outside the packaged app overrides stuff inside it.

Comment: The general order, yes (12., 13.); but nowhere does it explicitly talk about the same profile represented in both locations. I am confident that these are _somehow_ combined but not whether they're _supposed_ to be combined or, if so, _how_.

Comment: That is the order in which they are loaded, so external (12) overrides internal (13). As stated the order is pretty clear. They aren't merged, they are loaded and consulted in that order. So if you have property named `foo.bar` in `config/application-prod.yml` that takes precedence over  the internal `application-prod.yml`. If you also specify the `--foo.bar` as command line argument that even takes precedence over the files. Basically the order as stated, is the order in which the individual `PropertySource` instances are registered and consulted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.

My testing proves definitively that *some* settings from either file can be read (concretely, I successfully specified a log level locally that did not conflict with any bundled setting) but also that — sometimes — some settings cannot.

My experiment involved multiple profiles and restarts, some of which were definitely incorrectly specified. At times I also witnessed the unchanging settings occasionally changed but I'm uncertain if  that was methodology error; inattention; or if the behaviour is genuinely non-deterministic.

In any case, having to think about this question in the first place suggests that this approach may cause unexpected and unwanted surprises during operational maintenance.

Comment: The best way to verify this is to add Spring Boot actuators to your test app and view the response from the `/acuator/env` endpoint. In your case, you will see separate entries in the `propertySources` array for each file, with names like `applicationConfig: [file:./config/application-prod.yml]`, `applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-prod.yml]`, `applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]` indicating where each PropertySource was loaded from. This order is consistent and reliable, following the documented order of precedence that @m-deinum referred to above.